# how do i access an array returned as a pointer from a function using a subscript?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pointer-to-array

I have created a function that returns a pointer to an array of strings. The function should traverse a linked list and it should assign the data from each node into an array of string. Here is my function:

```
//function to traverse every node in the list
string *DynStrStk::nodeStrings(int count)
{
    StackNode *nodePtr = nullptr;
    StackNode *nextNode = nullptr;
    int i = 0;

    //Position nodePtr at the top of the stack
    nodePtr = top;

    string *arr = new string[count];

    //Traverse the list and delete each node
    while(nodePtr != nullptr && i < count)
    {
        nextNode = nodePtr->next;
        arr[i] = nodePtr->newString;
        nodePtr = nextNode;

        cout << "test1: " << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

i want to use that pointer to the array returned by the function above, and i want to assign it to a new array in a different function where it will test each subscript in that array for a condition.

i am having trouble accessing the new array and i can't even print out the string in each new array element.

```
arr = stringStk.nodeStrings(count);
cout << "pointer to arr of str: " << *arr << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    cout << "test2: " << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

this is my output after calling both functions:

```
test1: rotor
test1: rotator
test1: racecar
test1: racecar
pointer to arr of str: racecar //this test tells me i can get to array
test2: racecar
test2: 
test2: 
test2:
```

this is my expected output

```
test1: rotor
test1: rotator
test1: racecar
test1: racecar
pointer to arr of str: racecar
test2: racecar
test2: racecar
test2: rotator
test2: rotor
```

what am i doing wrong and how can i access each element in the new array from the second function??????

thanks!!!!

here is the second function using the pointer to the array:

```
int createStack(fstream &normFile, ostream &outFile)
{
    string catchNewString;
    string testString, revString;

    string *arr;

    int count = 0; //counts the number of items in the stack

    DynStrStk stringStk;

    while(getline(normFile,catchNewString)) // read and push to stack
    {
        stringStk.push(catchNewString); // push to stack
        //tracer rounds
        outFile << catchNewString << endl;
        count++;

    }


    arr = stringStk.nodeStrings(count);

    cout << "pointer to arr of str: " << *arr << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {

        cout << "test2: " << (arr[i]) << endl;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: When you print `"test1"`, also print `i` and you'll see the problem

Comment: You should return a vector in the first place, not a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to increment `i` in the function `DynStrStk::nodeStrings`. Therefore all your assignments are to `arr[0]`.

Comment: i am a complete fool sometimes. its always the smallest details that screw me. thanks for the look man i was trying to figure that one out for the past 2 hours.... like they say, its the devil thats in the details. thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don't want to "return" pointers to arrays.
What's the type of "arr" in the outside function?
Anyway, the subscript notation is valid, something else in your code is not.

Comment: its also a pointer to a string array. here is the function:

i am going to edit the question to include the entire function. take a look in a second

Comment: What is count's value?

Comment: its just counting how many nodes are in the stack being created. the data in each node in the linked list creating the stack is what i want to put into an array so i can test to see whether or not each string is a palindrome...

thanks again for your help!